# multiple HID input reports

Tags: windows, winapi, usb, hid

I declared two input reports (64B for the short report and 128B for the long report) with a 64B interrupt endpoint in packet size.

When reading the short report, the USB analyzer shows the expected number of bytes (64B) for the short report as being transferred, but ReadFile complains that my buffer is invalid (although it is large enough and numberOfBytesToRead = 64).

If I use the long report size for the numberOfBytesToRead parameter on the short report, ReadFile does not complain, but this is useless and clearly wrong. How can I fix this?

And I used multiples of interrupt endpoint in packet size to make things simple; what happens if my reports are not multiples?

I read that I need to use ZLP or short packet at the end of short reports because the HID driver expects reports of the longest size. So this is likely the problem. Is there an example of how to make ZLP in the SiLabs firmware? I am using the C8051F320.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to send a ZLP after the short reports if they are multiples of endpoint in packet size.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `ReadFile`, so clearly you are reading **packets**, not **reports**. That's an important distinction in HID. HID packets can be 8 bytes for low speed devices and 64 bytes for full speed devices.

Wikipedia links to the specifications which you should read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_interface_devices

The WDK contains some functions - all named `Hid_*` that allow to interact with HID devices as well and will already perform some preprocessing. But how useful that is depends whether your device is of one of the HID classes for which those shortcuts exist ...

For the rest of the question you should post a little bit of code and you should also tell us exactly what return codes you get where. I'll probably edit my answer once more details come in from your end.